# Polynomial with degree 2n, show that equation has $n$ different roots.

Tags: complex-analysis

> We have polynomial $F(z) = (x+i)^{2n+1} - (x-i)^{2n+1}$ with 2n
>    degree. $F(\cot(\alpha)) = 0$
>   Show the equation has n different roots $\alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_{n} \in  (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Sketch:
Using $F(x) = W(x^{2})$ for W as polynomial with degree n. It shows that $F(x)$ have couples roots with sign. 
But I am a bit confusing how to prove that $F(\cot(\alpha)) = 0$ ?
Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I can't make sense of this. What is $\alpha$?

Comment: $cot(\alpha) = x $ It's means that we transform polynomial to other form.

Comment: So what you mean is "Show that the equation $F(\cot\alpha)=0$ has $n$ different roots" etc. Which is not quite what you wrote.

Comment: It's means that exist $\alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_n \in (0,\pi/2)$ such that $F(\cot(\alpha))=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x) = (x+i)^{2n+1} - (x-i)^{2n+1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in the variable $x^2$ or degree $2n$ in $x$.

On the range $(0,\pi/2)$, $\cot(\alpha)$ takes all positive values and therefore you are being asked to prove that $F(x)=0$ has $n$ different positive roots.

Now $F(x)=0$ if and only if $\frac{x+i}{x-i}=w$, where is a $2n+1$th root of unity. Then $x=\frac{w+1}{w-1}i$.

Let $w$ and $t$ be two different such roots of unity. If they gave the same solution for $x$ we would have $\frac{w+1}{w-1}=\frac{t+1}{t-1}$. Then $wt-w+t-1=wt+w-t-1$ and so $w=t$. We therefore have $2n+1$ different numbers of the form $\frac{w+1}{w-1}i$.

Now consider a circle centre $w$ and radius $1$. Then the origin lies on the circle and $w\pm1$ are on the diameter. By the 'angle on a diameter is a right angle' result $\frac{w+1}{w-1}i$ is real.

$w=-1$ gives $x=0$ which is not a solution. Since $F$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $x^2$, the $2n$ real roots occur in pairs of roots each the negative of the other. Hence there are precisely $n$ positive roots as required.

Comment: Many good solutions, very clear

Comment: Very pleased to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
If $\ (x+i)^{2n+1}-(x-i)^{2n+1}=0\ $, then $\ \frac{x+i}{x-i}\ $ must be a $\ (2n+1)^\text{th}\ $ root of unity. That is,
$$
\frac{x+i}{x-i}=e^\frac{2\pi ij}{2n+1}\ .
$$
for some $\ j=0,1\dots, 2n\ $. Can you take it from there?